# GCP Cloud SQL Point-in-time recovery

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql, data-recovery, disaster-recovery

I am working on DR for Cloud SQL. I found that we can enable Point in time recovery for Cloud SQL and get the data restored till a particular time in case of any data corruption.
In the document, I found that we will have to create a clone after enabling point in time recovery.
Creating a clone will create a new IP address for the [cloned database](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/backup-recovery/pitr?hl=en#perform-pitr). Will the admin credentials going to change when we create a clone of the database or is it going to be the same?

Comment: The database credentials will be the same.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [link](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2014/04/more-control-over-your-cloud-sql-database-with-point-in-time-recovery-and-custom-flags.html):

> Point-in-time recovery allows you to recover an instance to a specific point in time. For example, if an operator ‘fat finger’ error causes a loss of data you can
> recover a database to the state it was just before the error occurred. It’s also great for testing your application and diagnosing issues since you can clone your live data to a testing database. See the [point-in-time-recovery](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/backup-recovery) docs for more information.

Admin credentials will be the same for both databases. For more information you refer to the [link](https://blog.dbi-services.com/recovery-in-the-%E2%98%81-with-google-cloud-sql-postgresql/) where recovery with the Google Cloud SQL(postgreSQL) has been explained.

Comment: @Vikash Kumar Posted an answer, Is it helpful?